# How to create a CDI bean per cucumber scenario

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, cdi, cucumber-jvm

**Background:**
I am very new to CDI, but have been using cucumber, selenium and Java combination as End-to-End test for a while. Recently, I am implementing CDI to my e2e test project, but I found there is no kind of ScenarioScoped like "DI framework Guice" in CDI. Because I want to inject a new selenium webdriver per every cucumber scenario. I have searched a lot online, found a lot of tutorial introducing different scopes but none of them talking about ScenarioScoped nor how to custom such scope in CDI.

**Goal:**
I would like to create a such CDI bean, so that it initialize a new selenium webdriver every cucumber scenario.

**My current code:**
A webdriver producer method, (Since there is no ScenarioScoped, I am using ApplicationScoped, but don't work as I need.)

```
@Produces
@TheWebDriver
@ApplicationScoped
public WebDriver get() {

    return iWebDriver;
}
```

In a page driver class:

```
@Inject
public LandingPageDriver(@TheWebDriver WebDriver aDriver) {
        iCalculator = find( aDriver, By....);
        iWelcome = find( aDriver, By....);
}
```

In my step definition class:

```
@Inject
private LandingPageDriver iMainToDoListPageDriver;
```

Questions:
Is this possible to create CDI per cucumber scenario? If so, please refer me to a code sample or just even a tutorial?
If not possilbe, please let me know the reason and provide me with an alternative. 
Or if I am doing something don't make sense, please correct me.

All helps are appreciated!Please let me know if you need more info.

Comment: First off, are you sure you want your WebDriver to be so short lived? Having to relaunch your browser on each scenario seems less efficient.  Second, if you use @DependentScoped the bean should only exist as long as the thing needing the bean needs it. I think with Cucumber's Weld implementation, that should be on a scenario basis. Personally, I keep the browser around as long as I can and delete cookies or other things to manage state.

Comment: Its an interesting idea.  I agree though, not sure I would tie the webdriver to that.  There is no scenario scope, however you can implement a custom CDI context to provide such a thing.  You can leverage a scenario hook http://zsoltfabok.com/blog/2012/09/cucumber-jvm-hooks/ to know when to setup and teardown the context.

Comment: Hi @DanWoodward, to answer your first question, I use selenium grid and found that if the node don't close its browser after a test ends, the node can not assign another test to it. Then, I GUESS if I destroy the injected webdriver , the browser will be closed. Second question: in the [WELD doc](http://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/latest/en-US/html/scopescontexts.html#_the_dependent_pseudo_scope) , it says "An instance of a dependent bean is never shared between different injection points." I guess I want to share webdirver between different page objects. Am I understanding correctly? Thanks.

Comment: Well, that's a good point. If @Dependent does that, it might be an issue. I'm still learning Weld myself, only using certain parts of it for now (just learned how to write annotations in it, to allow a behavior to wrap around a single step def). You might look at the hooks, as recommended above. I'll have to remember this when I work on my own GRID stuff at a later date.

Comment: Hi @JohnAment, I am trying the scenario hook. However, I couldn't add CDI bean destroy inside of the "@After" method. Am I on the right way?

Comment: Hi @NealSha, `@Dependent` behaviour indeed does not share the instances (the idea is to avoid using proxy and create a new instance per injection point), so the custom scope looks like an option here. From pure CDi point of view (dunno cucumber) custom scope seems viable and reasonable based on your description. As for guides and code, there will be some more official source under Weld Github soon, but at the very moment I can redirect you to [Martin's repo showing basic custom scope setup](https://github.com/mkouba/command-context-example). Though its just code yet, it might help you.

Comment: Hi @Siliarus, thanks for the reference, I will take a look when I really need to create custom scope. Because I have made some changes in selenium side to comfort the lack of "scenariosoped".